# Windows 8.1 WCF client fails to connect to service with digest authentication over BasicHttpBinding

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication, digest-authentication

I am having an issue with my WCF application when connecting a client from Windows 8.1. I've been going crazy over this the last couple of days, and cannot get to the bottom of it. Here is the scenario:

My WCF service is fairly straight forward. It uses a basicHttpBinding, with TransportCredentialOnly security mode, and digest client credential type. (The web.config file is here: http://pastebin.com/LsWmcfTs). It does it this way as I need the windows identity on the server side.

My client is a console application, the failure happens when it attempts to invoke the 'Ping' method in my service (which simply returns the text 'Pong') The code used to connect to the service is below:

```
var basicBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
basicBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Digest;

var client = new TestExecutionEngineClient(basicBinding, new EndpointAddress(uri));

client.Open();

client.Ping();
```

This has been working for over a year on all connecting clients All except for Windows 8.1 that is, where it never has worked.

When it hits client.Ping(); I get the exception below:

Exception:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Digest'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+v1c1d404aaeb7edbba8daf132fea97aa12243033a0f40acf01376892331a408411c85513f482eab750b18498cb2d420b2fb99998b5b8b071a2",charset=utf-8,realm="Digest"'.

Inner Exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Base Exception:

> No credentials are available in the security package

From what i can tell, it looks like server side is requesting digest (correctly) and the client is authenticating in digest, but it won't accept it.....

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: According to MSDN there was a change in Windows 8.1 (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn344918.aspx). Is the user in question a member of the Protected Users group outlined in the change description?

Comment: That looked promising, however our DC is 2008 R2, and there is no security group in our AD called Protected Users... So naturally, my user account is not in it

Comment: Can you create a small app to self-host the service as opposed to IIS and see if it works?

Comment: Just done that, created a basic WCF service library, using the template, but added digest authentication. Ran the service and client on the same windows 8.1 box, i got the EXACT same exception.

Comment: Can you confirm with Fiddler that the 401 Unauthorized is not the challenge but the response to the challenge? Does WCF tracing provide any additional information?

Comment: Thanks for your replies... I'll have a look with fiddler. But I'm afraid I'm new to WCF tracing. Could you give me a pointer? Thanks

Comment: Just ran fiddler. There is no HTTP communication when I run the connecting client app. The only communication is to telemetry.microsoft.com, which i can only assume is a data collector when exceptions are thrown. It appears the exception is thrown locally before any communication happens. Seems the error is misleading:: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No credentials are available in the security package at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireDefaultCredential(SSPIInterface s, String p, CredentialUse i)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44646/discussion-between-kevin-and-tom-beech)

Comment: Having the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060953/httpwebrequest-with-digest-authentication-not-working-under-windows-8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Microsoft have enhanced the security in the LSAS in 8.1 / 2012 R2. BasicHttpBinding is no longer supported for sending the users identity information over the network. You must use WSHttpBinding instead.

This solved my problem